# How do you make a utility class handle differences in subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

This is probably a bad example, but please work with it. I have a super class `Cake` and two subclasses: `ExampleCake` and `SaleCake`. I also have a `Baker` who can reverse engineer a cake to bake a copy of it, and knows what to do with it afterwards.

(All pseudo code)

```
public class Cake{
   radius; 
   height;
   ingredients;
   color;
   name;
}

public class ExampleCake extends Cake{
   shelfLocation;
}

public class SaleCake extends Cake{
   owner;
}

public class Baker{
   Cake bakeCake(Cake);
   Cake bakeSaleCake(Cake, Owner);
   Cake bakeExampleCake(Cake, Location);

   void handleCake(Cake);
}
```

The Baker needs to know how to handle generic Cakes, ExampleCakes, and SaleCakes. So his bakeCake functions look something like this:

```
Cake bakeCake(cake){
   newCake = cake.copy();
   mixIngredients(newCake);
   putCakeInOven(newCake);
   putIcing(newCake);
   return cake;
}

Cake bakeSaleCake(cake, owner){
   newCake = bakeCake(cake);
   newCake.setOwner(owner);
   return newCake;
}

Cake bakeExampleCake(cake, location){
   newCake = bakeCake(cake);
   newCake.setLocation(location);
   return newCake;
}

void handleCake(cake){
   if(cake instanceof ExampleCake)
      putOnShelf((ExampleCake)cake);

   else if(cake instanceof SaleCake)
      giveToCustomer((SaleCake)cake);

   else
      putOnTable(cake);
}
```

My problem with this is that the Baker is hardcoded to only handle certain types of cakes. If new types of cakes comes along, he can't handle them. Is there a clean, generic way to handle that, or is the pseudocode I have above somewhat "good enough" (as in, it doesn't hurt your eyes or heart)?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the cloneable pattern, you simply need to let the `Cake` classes implement the method to copy themselves.

Comment: Makes sense as far as cake creation goes. I forgot to add the "handleCake" part, which I appended to the end of the pseudocode.

Comment: The handleCake part could probably be refactored using the visitor pattern.

Comment: Switching like that on the type is a code smell imho. If you need to know the exact type like that, you should never 'forget' it.

Comment: Using the visitor pattern, I think I would still have handle(SaleCake) and handle(ExampleCake) though, so it would still sort of still be a similar problem of not being able to handle new types of cakes.

Comment: @JornVernee Right, that's why I want to clean it up. Would you suggest splitting it out into separate functions like what Calculator kind of hints to?

Comment: My suggestion would be to either, pass a reference to the `Baker` as argument to `copy`, or pass it to the `Cake` constructor. In both cases the cake's implementation would call the appropriate method. You could also let the `Baker` decide the logic by using the command pattern, where you pass in a functor with a cake as parameter, that would only work with the constructor though, since you'd need to know the exact type.

Comment: I would let every cake implement `Bakeable` and let the `Cook` to `bake(Bakeable cake);` as well as `Handable` if every class have different handing scenario

Comment: Are you saying you would have each cake class implement Handable?  Could you describe further?

Comment: So did any of these help or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copying the cakes you can use copy-constructors. This way it is up to the specific cake how it copies itself. For handling arbitrary cakes you can use the visitor pattern. Via a visitor you can "ask" a cake about its type instead of checking the type with `instanceof`.

The code could look like this (You will want to have other Cake constructors in addition to the copy-constructors):

//Cake class

```
public class Cake{
   int radius; 
   int height;

   public Cake(Cake cake){
       this.radius = cake.radius;
       this.height = cake.height;
   }

   <R> R accept(CakeVisitor<? extends R> visitor){
       return visitor.visit(this);
   }

}
```

//ExampleCake class

```
public class ExampleCake extends Cake{
   String shelfLocation;

   public ExampleCake(Cake cake, String shelfLocation){
       super(cake);
       this.shelfLocation = shelfLocation;
   }

   <R> R accept(CakeVisitor<? extends R> visitor){
       return visitor.visit(this);
   }

}
```

//SaleCake class

```
public class SaleCake extends Cake{
   String owner;

   public SaleCake(Cake cake, String owner){
       super(cake);
       this.owner = owner;
   }

   <R> R accept(CakeVisitor<? extends R> visitor){
       return visitor.visit(this);
   }

}
```

//Visitor interface

```
public interface CakeVisitor<R> {

    R visit(Cake cake); 
    R visit(SaleCake cake);
    R visit(ExampleCake cake);

}
```

//Baker class

```
public class Baker {
    private final CakeVisitor<Void> cakeHandler = new CakeVisitor<Void>(){

        @Override
        public Void visit(Cake cake) {
            putOnTable(cake);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visit(SaleCake cake) {
            giveToCustomer(cake);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Void visit(ExampleCake cake) {
            putOnShelf(cake);
            return null;
        }

    };

    Cake bakeCake(Cake cake){
       return processedCake(new Cake(cake));
    }

    SaleCake bakeSaleCake(Cake cake, String owner){
       return processedCake(new SaleCake(cake, owner));
    }

    ExampleCake bakeExampleCake(Cake cake, String location){
       return processedCake(new ExampleCake(cake, location));
    }

    void handleCake(Cake cake){
        cake.accept(cakeHandler);
    }

    private <C extends Cake> C processedCake(C cake){
        mixIngredients(cake);
        putCakeInOven(cake);
        putIcing(cake);
        return cake;
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to handle a new type of cake with your Baker, it will be put on the table by default unless you provide a visit-method which accepts specifically objects of the new cake type. I think you can't really make it more generic than this, because when you have a new type of Cake, you want to handle it differently than the other types of cakes and the new code that handles it has to go somewhere. Code like `putOnTable()` shouldn't pe placed inside a cake class, because a cake doesn't know how it is put on a table - the baker knows -> therefore the visitor pattern.

Comment: That's pretty neat.  However it doesn't compile at private <C extends Cake> C processedCake(C cake) method.  I created mixIngrediant() and says "refering to missing type C".  What is the "C" class or what syntax is that exactly?  Thanks for writing this.

Comment: @NickZiebert The  `mixIngredients` method and the other methods in there, which I did not include, have to accept a cake of type `Cake`. Then it compiles since the generic type parameter C is defined to be a descendant of cake (descendants of `Cake` can be used where superclass `Cake` is required). `processedCake` returns the cake passed to it preserving its static type. I tried saving a few lines in the bake-methods doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Good design is about identifying between what behaviors change, and what stays the same, and then separating these two groups.  What is changing here is the Baker's behavior for each cake.  So we want to create a new class that can encapsulate his changing behavior.  This is how we do it.  Create an interface called BakerBehavior with a single method called doBehavior().  Then, create a class called PutOnShelfBehavior and another called GiveToCustomerBehavior, both implementing BakerBehavior.  Override the doBehavior() method.

Now, in each of your cake classes, you can create a PutOnShelfBehavior object or GiveToCustomerBehavior object.  Your cake Superclass will have an act() method that will look like this:

```
//Constructor {
myBehaviorObject=new PutOnShelfBehavior();
}

public void act() {
    myBehaviorObject.doBehavior();
}
```

Now, in your Baker class, this is what your handleCake method will look like:

```
private void handleCake(Cake cake) {
    cake.act();
}
```

I don't see any other way of doing this.  This has the advantage of A) Not having to hardcode cake types in that handleCake Class, B) You don't have to repeat any code (Maybe you have 2 different cake types that are put on shelf, for example).  C) Each cake doesn't know anything about the Baker, it just knows that it's going to be put on a shelf or whatever.  I hope someone can tell me if there is a better way of doing this, I'm intrigued by this question.